# Can you fix an HTML5 footer at the bottom of the screen on smart phones?

Tags: android, ios, html, css

I have one issue regarding footers in smartphone web-based applications (we are using HTML5 and CSS3).

I want the footer fixed at the bottom. But on mobile devices (iPhone, Android and BlackBerry) the footer is not displaying at the bottom. It will be scrolled up along with the rest of the page when I move it. Is there any way I can fix it to the bottom?

Thanks
Ashish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is very little support for `fixed` in the mobile webkit browsers.
You would probably have to use some sort of hack to position something at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply code a sticky footer, e.g. [sticky-footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)? I've just loaded that site on my Android phone and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed position chrome is one of the major reasons people go use a framework like our own Sencha Touch. It was NOT easy to do in a way that worked across mobile browsers.